# Connecting FireWire scanner to Thunderbolt port

Tags: 14.04, scanner, firewire, thunderbolt

Is it possible to connect an old FireWire film scanner to a Thunderbolt port by using a Thunderbolt to FireWire adapter (Apple MD464ZM/A)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a Bumblebee2 camera (from PointGrey) with a Firewire 400 connector to work through a Firewire 800 to Thunderbolt Apple adapter. I connected the camera to the adapter through a Firewire 400 to Firewire 800 cable. Following the below steps solved my problem.

- Installed the Firewire drivers 
    sudo apt-get install libraw1394-11
- added raw1394 to /etc/modules to force Linux to load the firewire kernel modules
- Modified some udev rules using a script provided by PointGrey. You may want to do something similar with your scanner.
- Restart the computer while the device is connected. Disconnecting and reconnecting the device still doesn't work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the udev mod you used from PointGrey? Also, what hardware are you running on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are four questions involved:

1. Do your Linux kernel and your PC's firmware cooperate well enough to detect devices that are attached at Thunderbolt (cold-plugged at least, or even better, hot-plugged)?  Can't answer that.
2. Is the FireWire controller in Apple's FireWire-to-Thunderbolt dongle work with Linux?  Yes, the firewire-ohci and firewire-core kernel drivers should work perfectly with this controller, which is an LSI FW643-e2 as far as I know.
3. Is your scanner working with Linux' SBP-2 (SCSI encapsulated over IEEE 1394) driver, firewire-sbp2?
4. Is your scanner supported by a scanning application on Linux (e.g. SANE or VueScan)?

Regarding question 3 and 4, I have two FireWire flatbed scanners myself, an Epson Perfection 2450 Photo and a Umax PowerLook 1100.  The Epson works, but the Umax does not, but the precise source of the Umax's trouble is not known to me.